# How to delete lines containing a string that is from another file?

Tags: bash, awk

Suppose I have file named `data`:

```
ID_11 0.3 0.5
ID_13 0.5 0.5
ID_14 0.6 0.3
ID_15 0.7 0.8
ID_16 0.9 1.0
```

I also have another file `ID`:

```
ID_11
ID_16
```

I want to delete the lines in `data` where the first column of the line matches `ID`. The desired output is like this:

```
ID_13 0.5 0.5
ID_14 0.6 0.3
ID_15 0.7 0.8
```

How to do it?

I have found a command online. But I do not know whether is right or not. Can someone provide explanation?

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' ID file
```

Comment: Read the ID file first, and use the IDs as the keys of an array. Then read the data file, check if `$1` is not in the array, and print the line.

Comment: @81235 -- What did you already try?

Comment: You could also just use `grep -v -f ID data`.

Comment: That command looks correct, does it work?

Comment: @Barmar. can you provide explanation about the command? I am quite new about awk.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. Which part of the awk script don't you understand?

Comment: That script does exactly what I described in my first command.

Comment: @Barmar. what `FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)` stands for?

Comment: @Barmar. I found the result of `grep -v -f ID data` is different from `awk` command. Should it be `grep -vw -f ID data`

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `-w` option, which is needed to prevent matching substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command looks good to me, and it also works for me, let me explain the command:

```
$cat file1                                                                                         
ID_11 0.3 0.5
ID_13 0.5 0.5
ID_14 0.6 0.3
ID_15 0.7 0.8
ID_16 0.9 1.0
$cat file2                                                                                         
ID_11
ID_16
$awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1                                                
ID_13 0.5 0.5
ID_14 0.6 0.3
ID_15 0.7 0.8
```

1. `NR==FNR`  NR is number of record it keeps increase when you read one or more files, it is total file records number; FNR is file number of record it increases when read a file and reset to 0 when read another file, it is current file record number.
2. `a[$1]++;next`  If there's no `FS`(field separator) is provided, the default separator is space, in your case, `FS` is space, therefore no need to provide it. put field 1(ID_XX) into array `a` as index number, skip the rest use `next`
3. `!($1 in a)` execute when reads the second file, and if field 1 is not in array `a`, print it out.

Comment: @Barmar not exactly! with explanation:)

Answer (score 1):

This part of the script:

```
NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}
```

saves the values from the ID file into the array `a`.

`FNR` is the line number in the current file, `NR` is the line number in all input files. When they're equal, it means you're processing the first file. That's a common idiom you'll see in many scripts where the first file has a special role.

`a[$1]++` uses the first field as the key of an array and increments that array element. This will create the array element if necessary.

`next` goes to the next line in the input, so it skips over any other code blocks.

```
!($1 in a)
```

will be executed when processing the second input file. It tests whether the first field is not a key in the array that was created while processing the first file. Since there's no code block after it, the default action when a test is true is to print the input line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with grep:

```
$ grep -vFwf ID data
ID_13 0.5 0.5
ID_14 0.6 0.3
ID_15 0.7 0.8
```

The options do the following:

- `-v`: invert matches – print the lines that *don't* match
- `-F`: fixed strings – don't interpret pattern as regular expression (doesn't change result here, might accelerate things a little)
- `-w`: word matching – only match lines where the match is a whole word (avoids substring matching)
- `-f`: read patterns from file – interpret argument as file name instead of pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `join`:

```
join -v 1 data ID
```

By default, `join` uses the first field for the two files. 
The `-v 1` parameter displays only unpaired lines from the first file.

Answer (score -1):

```
for line in $(cat ID); do sed '/$line/d' data; done
```

I'm not sure how iteration is done on your specific shell, but something on the lines of the above.

Comment: This is so wrong. It will print the data file multiple times, each time just skipping one line.

Comment: What do you mean by "his specific shell"? The question is tagged `bash`, there's no `foreach` command in `bash`.